# starting apache drill process with java API?

Tags: java, sql, scala, jdbc, apache-drill

Hi I'm doing some experimentation with Drill for a prototype, and it works ok with "embedded" mode.
At the moment we use the maven dependency for `drill-jdbc-all` and a JDBC with:

```
Class.forName("org.apache.drill.jdbc.Driver")
val conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:drill:drillbit=localhost:31010")
[...]
```

I wonder if there is a way to start a drill instance directly using java API, without the need of launching it from console?
I've tried using the `jdbc:drill:zk=local` connection url also, but cannot find a way to start a local node with zookeeper. I've searched on the github, but without any luck.

Thanks in advance for any suggestion

Comment: Are you looking for jdbc connection via Zookeeper quorum or starting actual drillbit process (org.apache.drill.exec.server.Drillbit) using Java ? Not sure if there is api to start  drillbit process via java api. One way to do is to invoke drillbit.sh script with necessary arguments using remote ssh execution libraries like JSch.

Comment: At the moment I'm starting the embedded drill via commandline, then connect via JDBC by my Java (actually Scala) program, and it works.
As far as I know the commandline is a version of sqline, then I suppose that it initialize a drillbit instance, then work with it, it should be a way to do this by Java, I suppose.
The idea is trying to use an embedded library avoiding external services, so I'm trying to avoid zookeeper at the moment, but if there is a way for instance to launce an embedded zookeeper it should be good for me as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want run Drill on a single node completely programmatically you can look at the Drill unit tests for examples. Specifically the unit tests use the [ClusterFixture](https://github.com/apache/drill/blob/master/exec/java-exec/src/test/java/org/apache/drill/test/ClusterFixture.java) class to run Drill programatically. For an example of how to use the ClusterFixture to launch drill see **fifthTest** in [ExampleTest](https://github.com/apache/drill/blob/master/exec/java-exec/src/test/java/org/apache/drill/test/ExampleTest.java). **Note** all this code is in the test part of the Drill project, so you will have to copy this code (and all the other classes it depends on in the test packages) to use it in your project. If your interested in this being exposed as a library please post your thoughts to the Drill mailing list. Information about signing up for the Drill mailing list is [here](http://drill.apache.org/mailinglists/).

Comment: hi thanks very much for the suggestions!
I was looking for a test case but never find the specific one! I had to pause this experimentation for a while, but I'll restart it as soon as possible as you suggest!
thanks again